# Sql count returns a strange value in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, count

I created a query which suppose to return a number of counted rows. I tested my query using mysql query browser and it worked absolutely fine(it returns the correct result). However, when I used the same query in hibernate with addScalar method, it returned a rediciously large random number. For example, first time it may return 5390, the second time may return 9380 and the third time may be a different one for the expecting result which 1.

Does this mean hibernate doesn't support sql count function? Or what have I done wrong?

Here is some relevant code :

```
  String totalStr = ", count(e.event_date) as total ";

  //its a complex query but please pay attention to "count"
  final String sql = "select s.section_id, s.title as section_title, m.module_id, m.title as module_title, e.event_date as read_section_date, e.read_user_id, c.course_id as site_id " + totalStr +
                "from melete_course_module c, melete_module m, melete_section s, sakai_event se, " +
                "(select e.event, date_format(e.event_date, '%Y/%m/%d') as event_date ,(substring(e.ref, locate('/', e.ref)+1)) as read_section_id, (substring(e.ref, 1,  locate('/', e.ref)-1)) as read_user_id from sakai_event e) e " +
                "where c.course_id = :siteId and c.module_id = m.module_id and m.module_id = s.module_id and e.event = 'melete.section.read' and  s.section_id = read_section_id group by read_section_date";


    //retrieve data from the query.
    HibernateCallback hcb = new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                    //.addScalar("id", Hibernate.LONG)
                    .addScalar("site_id", Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("section_id", Hibernate.LONG)
                    .addScalar("section_title", Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("module_id", Hibernate.LONG)
                    .addScalar("module_title", Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("read_section_date", Hibernate.DATE)
                    .addScalar("read_user_id", Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("total", Hibernate.LONG);
            if(siteId != null) {
                q.setString("siteId", siteId);
            }
            List<Object[]> records = q.list();
            List<SectionVisits> results = new ArrayList<SectionVisits>();
            if(records.size() > 0){

                int index = 0;

                for(Iterator<Object[]> iter = records.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    Object[] s = iter.next();
                    SectionVisits c = new SectionVisitsImpl();
                    c.setId(index);
                    c.setSiteId((String)s[0]);
                    c.setSectionId(Long.valueOf(s[1].toString()));
                    c.setSectionTitle((String)s[2]);
                    c.setModuleId(Long.valueOf(s[3].toString()));
                    c.setModuleTitle((String)s[4]);
                    c.setDate((Date)s[5]);
                    c.setUserId((String)s[6]);
                    c.setCount(Long.valueOf(s[7].toString()));
                    results.add(c);     
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return results; 
        }
    };
    return (List<Stat>) getHibernateTemplate().execute(hcb);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your query and code where you use it

Comment: Please post your code for review

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not support subselects in from clouse. i tried many things and gave up when i found this jira issue.

see here https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3356

But if you have to use subselect you can create database views and use them in your sql as normal tables.